# construct insert function of linkedlist recursively

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

```html
def insert(self, index, item):
        """ (LinkedListRec, int, object) -> NoneType

        Insert item at position index in this list.
        Raise an IndexError if index > len(self).
        But note that it is possible to insert an item
        at the *end* of a list (when index == len(self)).
        """
        # Hint: take a look at remove and think about
        # what the base cases and recursive steps are.
        if index > len(self):
            raise IndexError
        if index == 1:
            self = self.insert_first(item)
        elif index > 1:
            self.rest = self.rest.insert(index-1,item)
def insert_first(self, item):
        """ (LinkedListRec, object) -> NoneType

        Insert item at the front of the list.
        Note that this should work even if the list
        is empty!
        """
        
        if self.is_empty():
            print("been")
            self.first = item
            self.rest = LinkedListRec([])
        else:
            temp = LinkedListRec([])
            temp.first = self.first
            temp.rest = self.rest
            self.first = item
            self.rest = temp
```

So I want to recursively construct the insert method. And I have changed some built-in function like **getitem** and len, so it could be used like list. But I dont know what I did wrong with this two. I can not get the function I desired.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment...  Is it?

Comment: No...I'm learning it by myself-- we did not even began this semester yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your methods return `None` (as you carefully document!) so in particular the assignment

```
self.rest = self.rest.insert(index-1,item)
```

destroys the list structure.  Remove the `self.rest =` part (and, though innocuous, the `self =` just above, for clarity if nothing else!) and that should help.  You may have other problems (I believe that the index for insertion may be meant to start from `0`) but this one is the one that immediately jumps out as most definitely wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my codes and now it finally works. It is the main reason.